# Haskell lambda expressions and simple logic formulas

Tags: haskell, lambda, logic

I have a misunderstanding while converting simple logic formula to lambda expression (proof of that formula).

So, I have the following formula:
((((A->B)->A)->A)->B)->B where -> means implication logical operator.

How can I write some lambda expression in any functional language (Haskell, preferably) corresponding to it?

I have some "results" but I am really not sure that it is correct way to do this:

- (((lambda F -> lambda A) -> A) -> lambda B) -> B
- ((((lambda A -> lambda B) -> A) -> A) -> B) -> B.

How can it be possible to tranform the formula into lambda expression? It will be very helpful if you know some material refers to this issue.

Thanks

Comment: This is a complex problem. The intuitionistic sequent calculus LJ and its related results play key roles in its "standard" solution. The Djinn tool is a "famous" implementation of a proof search in this system (roughly), and the Curry-Howard isomorphism allows to present these proofs as lambda terms.

Comment: Further, there's no such a thing as "converting" a formula into a lambda expression. That would amount to "converting" theorems into their proofs, which is nonsense -- theorems admits many distinct proofs, in general. At best, you can do proof search, where you look for one such proof.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I really glad to so much useful information in short time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a great time to use [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php)'s interactive mode.  It's like a game.  You can also do it manually but it's more work.  Here's what I did:

```
f : {A B : Set} -> ((((A -> B) -> A) -> A) -> B) -> B
f x = ?

Goal: B
x : (((A -> B) -> A) -> A) -> B
```

Basically the only move we have is to apply `x`, so let's try that.

```
f : {A B : Set} -> ((((A -> B) -> A) -> A) -> B) -> B
f x = x ?

Goal: ((A -> B) -> A) -> A 
x : (((A -> B) -> A) -> A) -> B
```

Now our goal is a function type, so let's try a lambda.

```
f : {A B : Set} -> ((((A -> B) -> A) -> A) -> B) -> B
f x = x (\y -> ?)

Goal: A 
x : (((A -> B) -> A) -> A) -> B
y : (A -> B) -> A
```

We need an `A`, and `y` can give it to us if we provide it with the right argument.  Not sure what that is yet, but `y` is our best bet:

```
f : {A B : Set} -> ((((A -> B) -> A) -> A) -> B) -> B
f x = x (\y -> y ?)

Goal: A -> B
x : (((A -> B) -> A) -> A) -> B
y : (A -> B) -> A
```

Our goal is a function type so let's use a lambda.

```
f : {A B : Set} -> ((((A -> B) -> A) -> A) -> B) -> B
f x = x (\y -> y (\z -> ?))

Goal: B
x : (((A -> B) -> A) -> A) -> B
y : (A -> B) -> A
z : A
```

Now we need a `B`, and the only thing that can give us a `B` is `x`, so let's try that again.

```
f : {A B : Set} -> ((((A -> B) -> A) -> A) -> B) -> B
f x = x (\y -> y (\z -> x ?))

Goal: ((A -> B) -> A) -> A
x : (((A -> B) -> A) -> A) -> B
y : (A -> B) -> A
z : A
```

Now our goal is a function type returning `A`, but we have `z` which is an `A` so we don't need to use the argument.  We'll just ignore it and return `z`.

```
f : {A B : Set} -> ((((A -> B) -> A) -> A) -> B) -> B
f x = x (\y -> y (\z -> x (\_ -> z)))
```

And there you go!

Comment: Wow! That is really best and quickest answer I've ever seen here. Thank you a lot. I've installed Coq and have tried to used it but I can't read the output. It is too complicated :(

Comment: I will try to use Agda following your advice. It is strange that we do not consider such applications and did all the things by hands even without mentioned rules! Thank you a lot.

Comment: Ehm, if I understood you right the answer can be rewritten in the following way:


x(lambda y -> y(\lambda z -> x (z))) ?

Comment: Not quite.  We don't apply `z` to `x`, but rather the function which ignores its argument and returns `z`.  In haskell this is written `const z` or `\_ -> z`, or `lambda q -> z` in your notation where `q` is any unused variable.